# How can I fetch distinct reords in a table with SQL

Tags: sql

I have redundancy data in the table where I have to fetch only distinct records in my table. Here my table data sample

[image]

I want to display only unique records,
which means the 4th and last record in the table. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: First 3 rows are duplicates for employee number 101, rest 4 are for 102 and the last 4 are duplicates for 103. So why do you say only 4th and last are unique?

Comment: Have you at least tried to code it?

Comment: Hint: Use the `DISTINCT` keyword...

Comment: sorry for not being clear .. the condition is if dept is duplicate then it should be avoided and salary duplicate is should be avoided .. for empno which has unique dept and sal should be displayed

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want departments with only one emp no associated (that is the only explanation I could think of finding common between 4th and last row). Assuming this is it, try following query:

```
SELECT MAX(empno) empno, Dept, MAX(salary) salary
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Dept
HAVING Count(0) = 1;
```